# Google Chart not appearing on Firefox, IE or Safari

Tags: javascript, charts, cross-browser, google-visualization

I've created a simple pet-project website that uses Google Chart line graphs, and while everything appears fine on Chrome, the graphs aren't appearing on other browsers.

You can see the site in question here:
http://www.gta-bawsaq-billionaire.com/stock/xbox360/GOT

I cannot figure out what I've done wrong.

From looking around the web, I thought it might be something to do with Google's `google.setOnLoadCallback` not firing properly, so I tried surrounding that with:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { }
```

To see if it made sure the site was ready before attempting to load the chart, but it just timed out the entire page.

I don't believe I've made any mistakes in my options, they seem pretty straightforward:

```
        var options = {
            backgroundColor: '#2b2b2b',
            legend: {
                position: 'none'
            },
            animation: {
                startup: true,
                duration: 800,
                easing: 'out'
            },
            chartArea:{
                left:40,
                top:10,
                width: '100%',
                height: '90%'
            },
            vAxis: {
                gridlines: {
                    color: '#353535',
                    count: -1
                },
                baselineColor: '#555555',
                textStyle:  {color: '#555555' }
            },
            hAxis: {
                gridlines: {
                    color: '#2b2b2b',
                    count: 5
                },
                textStyle:  {color: '#555555' },
                baselineColor: '#2b2b2b',
                format:'MMM d'
            },
            width: 650,
            height: 300
        };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot I needed to change the date format from `Y-m-d` to `Y/m/d`!

Phew, working well now.